# Non-Numeric Argument To Binary Operator - Color In Plot

Tags: r

I am trying to create a plot which has observation/dot colour dependant on another variable. The variable is called treat and only consists of two strings "chilled" and "unchilled".

I have written the following code to obtain the graph:

```
chill_frame_four <- filter(chill_data, chill_data$spec %in% "Lolium perenne")
chill_plot_four %<a-% (plot(chill_frame_four$conc, chill_frame_four$photo, col=c("blue", "darkgreen")[as.numeric(chill_frame_four$treat)], pch=16,
                      xlab="CO2 Concentration (PPM)", ylab="Photosynthetic Rate  (µmol m-2 s -1)", main = expression(italic("Lolium Perenne"))) +
                      legend(x = "bottomright", legend = c("Chilled", "Unchilled"), pch = 16, col=c("blue", "darkgreen"), bty = "n", xpd=TRUE, title="Treatment Type", cex= 0.75))
```

When chill_plot_four object is called, the graph outputs and appears as expected, as shown in screenshot below.

[image]

However I am getting an error on console as shown below:

```
Error in plot(chill_frame_four$conc, chill_frame_four$photo, col = c("blue",  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

The graph appears to be working, but error is appearing in console. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

chill_frame_four data: https://gist.github.com/SakshamInABox/25ca2d6bf37076a9ec7eb62f9effef88

Comment: What do you get when you run `c("blue", "darkgreen")[as.numeric(chill_frame_four$treat)]`?

Comment: You are telling it to make a numeric value out of text. Try using col=factor(chill_frame_four$treat) and then add an extra argument n your ggplot: + scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "darkgreen"))

Comment: @mickey I get a 42 observation output varying between darkgreen and blue.

@JaredC same error 
`Error in plot(chill_frame_four$conc, chill_frame_four$photo, col = factor(chill_frame_four$treat),  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Have also tried as.factor.

Comment: Maybe try `col = ifelse(chill_frame_four$treat == [one of the levels], "blue", "darkgreen")`, but this might be barking up a wrong tree. It would help if you posted a sample of the data where the error shows up.

Comment: Same error unfortunately
`Error in plot(chill_frame_four$conc, chill_frame_four$photo, col = ifelse((chill_frame_four$treat ==  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Full line:
`col=ifelse((chill_frame_four$treat == "chilled"), "blue", "darkgreen")`

Comment: @mickey data of chill_frame_four https://gist.github.com/SakshamInABox/25ca2d6bf37076a9ec7eb62f9effef88

Comment: One thing that would make it easier to get help is if you eliminate all the extraneous code that is not involved in the issue.  For example the title the legend etc.   Even the transformations could be done outside --- and you could eliminate the piping too.

Comment: `plot(CO2$conc, CO2$uptake, col=c("blue", "darkgreen")[as.numeric(CO2$Treatment)], pch=16)`  worked for me without any message.

Comment: @Elin can confirm worked for me too just now, the error appears again when I add the legend into the object. Trying to figure out which part of legend is causing this

Comment: @Elin replacing the + symbol in the whole pipe with %>% seems to make the error go away, however it is spewing out some other numbers (that aren't errors), reckon that was the issue?

Comment: Replace the + before legend() with either `;` or put the legend function on a new line.  The `+` between elements is a ggplot idiom not the R base plottting.      Don't know what the numbers are though.